# how to get values from model and display in controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am making a site in codeigniter, here is my controller, model and view:

controller:

```
function checking()
 {
 $email=$this->input->post('email');
 $this->load->model('login_model');
 $data['dbemail']=$this->login_model->email();// assign your value to CI variable  
 $this->load->view('home', $data); //passing your value to view
 }
```

model:

```
public function email()
 {
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT email FROM change_password");
   $result = $query->result_array();
   return $result;
 }
```

view:

```
foreach ( $dbemail as $new_dbemail )
   {
      echo $new_dbemail['database_field'];//in here you can get your table header. 
     //Ex if your table has name field and you need to sho it you can use $new_dbemail['name'] 
    }
```

but i want to get $new_dbemail['name']  in my controller, how i can get the value of $new_dbemail['name'] in controller rather than view ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so... you have to fetch data into a **row_array** not in **result_array** in Model.

**Controller**

```
function checking()
{
$email=$this->input->post('email');
$this->load->model('login_model');
$data['dbemail']=$this->login_model->email();  
$database_field = $data['dbemail']['database_field']; //to get result in controller
$date['database_field'] = $data['dbemail']['database_field']; //to get result in view
$this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function email()
{
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT email FROM change_password");
return $query->row_array();   
}
```

**View**

```
<p> Database Field value : <?=$database_field;?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Calling the Model In A Variable :-

```
$data['dbemail']=$this->login_model->email();
```

So in this you have the results which you are fetching from Database. Than you passing this variable data to your View.

```
$this->load->view('home', $data);
```

So you already have the value in controller which u fetched from model which is stored in $data.

You can View the Values of $data , using

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

and it will show what data you are receiving

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

In controller...

```
function checking()
 {
 $email=$this->input->post('email');
 $this->load->model('login_model');
 $dbemail=$this->login_model->email();//array containing all emails
 //For each loop here for displaying emails
 foreach($dbemail as $email){
   $mail = $email; //assigning to variable
   echo $mail."<br/>";//displaying email
   }

 $data['dbemail'] = $dbemail;//for passing to view
 $this->load->view('home', $data); //passing your value to view
 }
```

Comment: That is an odd code, You don't just echo things from the controller!

Comment: @jtheman He is selecting emails only and want to  get email value in controller.

Comment: No that is not what he is asking. "but i want to get $new_dbemail['name'] in my controller, how i can get the value of $new_dbemail['name'] in controller rather than view ???" – Still - You don't echo() from the controller in CI, You use a view for output!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fetch the name from the database in the model. Change the query line:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT name, email FROM change_password");
```

Then to use the name data in the controller you could try this:

```
function checking()
{
   $email=$this->input->post('email');
   $this->load->model('login_model');
   $data['dbemail']=$this->login_model->email();
   $name = $data['dbemail']['name']; // example usage to retrieve name in controller
   $this->load->view('home', $data); 
}
```

Now the name data is available as `$name` in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
public function checking()
 {
 $email=$this->input->post('email');
 $this->load->model('login_model');
 $data['dbemails']=$this->login_model->email(); 
 $this->load->view('home', $data); //passing your value to view
}
```

Model

```
public function email()
{
$this->db->select("email"); // the row of the table you want to select.
$this->db->get('change_password'); //table name. you can still use your query, its just much neat when you use a specific query builder. 
$result = $this->result(); //giving you a result of type object
return $result;
}
```

View

```
foreach ( $dbemails as $dbemail )
 {
  echo $dbemail->email; // the '->' will be the identifier of which row you want to get or display, i assume its email beacause you specify it in the model. 
}
```

Hope this what your looking for.